# Windows VPN error: Access to the specified file handle have been revoked

Tags: vpn, remote-access, windows-10-preview, windows-server-2012-r2

I created a VPN server on Windows Server 2012 R2 using Windows Remote Access. Then I try to connect to it from Windows 10 Technical Preview, but after I press connect I get an "Access to the specified file handle has been revoked" error (see image below). What can be the cause of it, how can I make it work?

I port forwarded on router and enabled on Windows Firewall TCP port 47 and 1723.

[image: VPN error: Access to the specified file handle has been revoked]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of this misterious error: It writes the message of the System Error 806 ("Access to the specified file handle has been revoked."), but it is actually a VPN Error 806: "A connection between your computer and the VPN server has been established but the VPN connection cannot be completed."

Searching for that I realized, that I port forwarded TCP port 47 instead of IP protocoll 47 (GRE), after fixing this (and minor authentication problems) the VPN connection works.